# Is there a timer function that doesn't depend of key press

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to implement a timer in my program and i've tried using time.time() but my time taken value is depended on when I completely terminate the program, not when the final output occurs. So, if i don't terminate the program and wait, the time is longer than if i just immediately end the program. Is there an alternative or am i just using it wrong?

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time

t0 = time.time()

(code block)

cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
t1 = time.time()
total = print(t1-t0)
```

I need the timing after the last function cv2.imshow() is completed, but the timer keeps running until I close the program.

Comment: I think you should move the `t1 = time.time()` above `cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix for your problem would be:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time

t0 = time.time()

(code block)

t1 = time.time()
total = print(t1-t0)

cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Explanation:
The `cv2.imshow()` method accompanied with `cv2.waitkey()` blocks the main thread and hence preventing any code execution after the line `cv2.imshow()` unless and until you explicitly close the `imshow` window. So I would suggest you to move your time calculations before `cv2.imshow()`

Comment: This works, thanks! I suppose there isn't a function that can time the code block but still output an image, with cv2.waitKey()?

Comment: You should use `cv2.imwrite()` to view the images for debugging purposes. `cv2.imshow()` is fancy but it fails in some cases such as images with alpha channel, floating number type images, etc. Better use `cv2.imwrite()`